# Python3 tkinter metodo destroy

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

boa noite,

Eu estava a trabalhar num projeto que envolvia uma interface gráfica e decidi utilizar o tkinter para a produzir

Eu li sobre um metodo chamado destroy() mas não consegui de forma alguma encontrar uma maneira de o utilizar
o objetivo era destruir o Frame q contem a palavra 'ola' (isto e para testar e ter uma ideia)
[image: minha interface tkinter]

Nao sei se alguem conhece como utilizar este metodo ou se existem metodos mais eficazes do que este,estou aberto a sugestoes

obrigado e boa noite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o nome diz, o método `destroy` serve para destruir o widget criado. Caso você utilize o método em um `Label`, apenas este objeto será destruído. Caso você utilize o método em um `Frame` contendo dois `labels`, ele será destruído junto com as `labels`.

Isso acontece porque o método `destroy`, destrói o widget junto com outros widgets dentro dele ( widgets filhos ). É importante dizer que uma vez chamado o método `destroy`, o widget **nunca** mais poderá ser usado.

Existe um outro método chamado `forget`. De longe, este método é parecido com o `destroy`, porém ele é completamente diferente. O método `forget` irá simplesmente esconder o widget, porém o mesmo não será destruído. Isso é bom porque você pode "apagar" o widget temporariamente e depois voltar a usá-lo.

Veja alguns exemplos abaixo:

**UTILIZANDO O MÉTODO DESTROY:**

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button

def destroy():
    window.destroy()
    print("FINALIZADO!")

window = Tk()
Button(window,text="Destroy",command=destroy,bg="white").pack()
window.mainloop()
```

**UTILIZANDO O MÉTODO FORGET:**

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button,Label

def hide_or_show():
    global show

    if show:
        show = False
        text.forget()
        button["text"] = "Show"
    else:
        show = True
        text.pack()
        button["text"] = "Hide"

show = True
window = Tk()
button = Button(window,text="Hide",command=hide_or_show,bg="white")
button.pack()
text = Label(window,text="Hello World",fg="red")
text.pack()
window.mainloop()
```